# How to push back only one dimension of 2D vector

Tags: c++, arrays, vector

Okay, so i'm trying to create an AI that learns how to better play the sticks game as it wins, so if it wins, it stores the numbers it won with, so it has a better likelihood of choosing them again. I've declared a 2D vector:`vector<vector <int> > AI;` and initialized it. 
{

```
int c;
int rows = 3;
AI.resize(columns, vector<int>(rows, 0));
AI[0][0] = 0;
AI[0][1] = 0;
AI[0][2] = 0;
AI[1][0] = 1;
AI[1][1] = 1;
AI[1][2] = 1;
AI[2][0] = 1;
AI[2][1] = 1;
AI[2][1] = 2;
for (c = 3; c < 100; c++)
{
    AI[c][0] = 1;
    AI[c][1] = 2;
    AI[c][2] = 3;
}`
```

Now I have an array tracking its moves, (moves are based off rand()) I just need to know, how do i extend AI[][this] dimension of the array with push back or otherwise. That way when the computer wins, it stores an extra value of whatever it chose, hence making it more likely to win. Thank you!!

Comment: You mean like `A[some_index].push_back(some_value)`?

Comment: I would think so? I am just not sure how to choose AI[][this] vector instead of AI[this][] one if that makes sense

Comment: `for (sticks = 100; sticks > 0; sticks--)
 AI[sticks].push_back(AItrace[sticks]);` Is this what you're trying to say? I'm trying to  copy from AItrace to AI at the same index, but when i run this, i get a vector out of bounds error as soon as it hits this function. @NathanOliver